# Android Component Based Design and Activity-Thread Communication

Tags: android, software-design

I am trying to create an android application which is essentially a platform for other developers to use(let's say a mobile health platform). In this platform, I am trying to implement a component based approach. I have several activities, a main logic thread(or service), and a couple of other threads and services which provide data.The main logic is where the developer will be working.

The question is, is this a good architecture considering android environment? If so, I am thinking of using **Messenger** class to provide communication between these components, is this the ideal solution for performance?

And also should i control the passage between activities in main logic, for example if user presses a button which launches an other activity should i send a message to main logic and start the next activity from there or change the activity from UI thread and let the main logic know about the activity change? Which leads to my next question how can i connect an activity to an existing thread(May be passing the threads Handler?)?

I am a beginner so i can't see clearly what problems might occur so I wanted to ask to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might be searching the same answer :

Turns out using `Messenger` was the perfect solution because it could be used for interthread, interprocess and thread-process communition with a sufficient performance rate.

But keeping ui dealing with it's own management was the better solution and i just had to report ui's state to my main thread which had control over all other components.